# NSRect vs. CoreGraphics

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, nsrect

I have a general question concerning drawing pretty simple shapes in an `NSView`. Is there a "rule" when to use the `NSRect` <strike>class</strike> struct (`drawrect`) versus using the `CoreGraphics` framework?
What I understood so far I could use either one for my osx application. Can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no `NSRect` *class* (it's a struct), you're referring to the `NSView` method `drawRect:`. Generally speaking, the Core Graphics framework is "lower-level" than the AppKit drawing methods, which are usually just "wrappers" around Core Graphics. It's also plain C instead of Objective-C, so AppKit is typically a bit easier to use, but you can mix and match freely between the two.

For example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    //This uses AppKit:
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:[self bounds]] fill];

    //This does the same, using Core Graphics:
    CGContextRef ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, NSRectToCGRect([self bounds]));
}
```

Comment: Hello omz, thank you for the answer. I assume there is no drawback in quality at either of these approaches, right?

Comment: No, under the hood, they do pretty much exactly the same thing.